# Does overriding PHP Constructor execute it twice?

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I have a class that opens a database connection in its __construct() function and let other classes override this method.

```
class db {
    __construct() {
        $this->db = new mysqli();
    }
}
```

and then

```
class theme extends db {
    __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $doing_more_stuff;
    }
}
```

My question is when the constructor has already opened a database connection and i let for example my theme class override this constructor (just because i need a self constructor in theme) would the database connection be opened twice?

i thought about building a controling function in my db class that looks if there is already a connection like:

```
__construct() {
    if($no_connection) { $open_connection; } else { $use_opened_connection; }
}
```

So, is this good practice or at least ok?

Thanks

EDIT: Sorry, yesterday i started another question and it was in cache so the title was changed.

Comment: *I have a class that opens a database connection in its __construct() function and let other classes override this method.* Aside from your question - which is good although there are plenty of answers to it - I always found this sketchy. The second you instantiate this class, a database connection will be formed right up until the object is uninstantiated. In tiny applications, this can be alright. In large applications, this can be disastrous or have unexpected consequences. What happens if you have 50 objects? Or maybe even 5000? That's a LOT of connections...

Comment: So as long as theme is only initiated once a time, its ok? I also dont need to check it? I forgot: Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it does not execute twice. Upon `new theme`. `theme::__construct` and only `theme::__construct` is executed, as it overrides `db::__construct`. Inside that function, you explicitly call `parent::__construct` once, which executes `db::__construct` once.

This would be trivial to test by adding an `echo` statement…

Comment: But there are other classes that also use the db class, thats irrelevant in that case? Right, i will try a print_r() on db, thank you :D

Comment: One `new` equals one execution of the constructor. If you have several `new` which invoke this constructor, then it's going to be called every time.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a static member to avoid multiple connections.

Something like this:

```
class db {
    public static $_connection = false;

    public function __construct() {
        if (!self::$_connection) {
            self::$_connection = $this->connect();
        }
        return self::$_connection;
    }
}
```